# freenas old ui conflict with materialize material design

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, materialize

I need to **introduce material design in my old freenas** UI and make it look like **new freenas UI (Angular Material Design)** but In old freenas there is no Angular. So Now I am using materialize material design with dojo and dojango, but I continuosly face conflicts. Is there any Default Material Design for FreeNAS UI. I already tried:

1. MDBootstrap
2. Google Material Design
3. Materialize Material Design
4. MUI (Needs ReactJS)

And many others But None of them helping me to change freeNAS Project UI. Please Help me to fix this issue

**Thanks in Advance**